# Does the Time triggered Azure function scale as the increase in the instances of the App service plan?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, autoscaling, azure-app-service-plans

I have an Azure function that is triggered every 1 second.
Every time it is triggered, it reads a batch of messages from a Service Bus queue and processes them.
It runs on App service plan which scales on the active messages in the queue.
However as the service plan scales out I do not see any increase in the throughput of the function.

Does the Time triggered Azure function scale as the increase in the instances of the App service plan?

Answer (score 6):

No, Timer triggers are singletons. That means that at any given moment only one instance will be firing Function calls on timer.

Obviously, different Functions have independent invocations.

To scale processing of Service Bus messages you should use Service Bus Trigger directly, which can manage scaling for you.

Comment: Thanks @Mikhail, service bus trigger would not work for me as I need to process messages in batches, so timer seem to the only option. I am trying to bring another queue in the equation and have it trigger what the timer is doing now, hoping for that to scale,